# How to retain the access of cases to manually shared user after changing owner of that case?

Tags: case, manual-sharing

I have manually shared the case ownership to multiple users. But when I take that case ownership to specific user then all other user not able to access that case. I Want to retain the sharing among multiple users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the Owner of a record all the manual sharings are deleted so you will have to share the record with other users again.

Comment: I did the same, it works fine for the some cases but, for some cases I got UNABLE TO LOCK ROW EXCEPTION

Answer (score 2):

Best way to handle this situation is to create Case Team and add users to the Case Team for that Case. You can define team role and provide Read Only/Read Write access.

This way irrespective of Case ownership, those users defined in the Case Team will access the case.

For more information refer this link:

[Case Teams](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=caseteam_def.htm)

Comment: for each case depending on city field multiple users of same city get access of that case. So How I add user the case team?

Comment: That's a different question. First close this question and put a new question